# clickOutside triggers on the excluded class

Tags: angular

Here is such a template, when clicking on "Select All", `clickOutside` should not be triggered, but it works

Why does directive behave like this who understands?

```html
    <div
        [exclude]="'li.select-all-regions'"
        (clickOutside)="close($event)"
        >
            <ul class="regions">
                   <li 
                     (click)="selectAllRegions()"
                     class="select-all-regions">
                    Select All
                   </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

[console.log(event)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOFfy.png)

Comment: (clickOutside)="close($event)" is not a directive, I believe. Perhaps you are trying to accomplish something of the sort: https://medium.com/@ajantha.p.bandara/angular-8-9-click-outside-directive-2f0062837f9e?
However, in that case, you should add the actual directive to the div element.
In any case, what I would advise you to do is add event.stopPropagation() to your selectAllRegions() method:
* (click)="selectAllRegions($event)"
* selectAllRegions(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}